# Bind mount /proc or /dev in container got operation not permitted error

Tags: ubuntu, containers, mount, runc

I'm trying to bind mount /proc or /dev from host to linux container on ubuntu 16.04, but got **operation not permitted** error.

I am using [runc](https://github.com/opencontainers/runc) as my container runtime, and here is the mount section in runc config.json.

```
   {
        "destination": "/test-proc",
        "options": [
            "rbind",
            "ro"
        ],
        "source": "/proc",
        "type": "bind"
    },
```

And I have both pid namespace, user namespace and mount namespace turned on.

Here is the strace output:

> 22435 mount("/proc", "/sompath/test-proc", 0xc42001be56, MS_RDONLY|MS_BIND|MS_REC, NULL) = 0
>
> 22435 mount("/proc", "/somepath/test-proc", 0xc42001be66, MS_RDONLY|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND|MS_REC, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)

This issue only happens on Ubuntu but not other linux distribution such as Alinux or Raspbian.

Does anyone know what is the reason could cause this?